# How can I modify Windows registry programmatically?

Tags: powershell

Which programming language I can use to modify Windows registry? Can I use js or powershell?

Comment: What do you mean by "use in regedit"? In regedit you can use only mouse and keyboard.

Comment: as I remember in regedit values we can run windows script host commands. Can we use alternative tools or framework in regedit values?

Comment: You can use many programming languages to modify the _contents_ of the registry. That's quite different than using a programming language _in regedit_

Comment: I didn't mean "to modify the content" I mean putting commands in regedit values so we can put script in ram not disk.

Comment: https://www.welivesecurity.com/2017/05/15/malicious-registry-keys-reflective-injection/ like this one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any programming languages that provide access to [Win32 API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions): C++, C#, Visual Basic, Java, Python and many others.